# Why max(id) with join not working or how to optimize it with join?

Tags: mysql, optimization, join, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-8.0

**Below is my `MESSAGES_THREAD` table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `messages_thread` (
  `id` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `creator` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `other` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `messages_thread_creator_index` (`creator`),
  KEY `messages_thread_other_index` (`other`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

**Below is my `MESSAGES` table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `threadId` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT ''0'' COMMENT ''0->sent, 1->deliveried, 2->seen'',
  `time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `data_url` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `messages_threadId_status_index` (`threadId`,`status`),
  KEY `index5` (`userId`),
  KEY `message_threadId_id_index` (`threadId`,`id` DESC),
  CONSTRAINT `messages_messages_thread_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`threadId`) REFERENCES `messages_thread` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `messages_user_userId_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user` (`userId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2522 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

I want to get the last message id from `MESSAGES` table according to its threadId and to doing this i tried below two `Queries` both result are ok but those are not so **efficient**. Second `Query` seems quite efficient but not up-to the mark I accepted. How can I write this `Query` **efficiently**?

---

**Below is First `QUERY`:**

```
SELECT max(m.id), mt.other 
FROM messages_thread mt 
join messages m ON mt.id = m.threadId 
WHERE mt.creator=1 
group by mt.other;
```

**Below it's Graphical Execution Plan:**

[image]

**Below it's Session Status:**

```
Handler_commit  1
Handler_delete  0
Handler_discover    0
Handler_external_lock   4
Handler_mrr_init    0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  1
Handler_read_key    41
Handler_read_last   0
Handler_read_next   2561
Handler_read_prev   0
Handler_read_rnd    0
Handler_read_rnd_next   0
Handler_rollback    0
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  0
Handler_write   0
```

---

**Below is Second `Query` (which seems little bit optimized):**

```
SELECT m2.id, mt.other 
FROM messages_thread mt 
inner join ( select max(id) id, threadId 
           from messages m 
           group by threadId) as m2 on mt.id=m2.threadId
WHERE mt.creator=1;
```

**Below it's Graphical Execution Plan:**

[image]

**Below it's Session Status:**

```
Handler_commit  1
Handler_delete  0
Handler_discover    0
Handler_external_lock   4
Handler_mrr_init    0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  1
Handler_read_key    122
Handler_read_last   1
Handler_read_next   0
Handler_read_prev   0
Handler_read_rnd    0
Handler_read_rnd_next   41
Handler_rollback    0
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  0
Handler_write   40
```

---

### Query Execution details with `LATERAL` for suggested by member Madhur Bhaiya

**Below is the Query suggested by Madhur Bhaiya `LATERAL`:**

```
SELECT m2.id, mt.other 
FROM messages_thread mt 
join lateral (select max(m.id) as id
               from messages m 
               where m.threadId = mt.id ) as m2
WHERE mt.creator=1;
```

**Below it's Graphical Execution Plan:**

[image]

**Below it's Session Status:**

```
Handler_commit  1
Handler_delete  0
Handler_discover    0
Handler_external_lock   4
Handler_mrr_init    0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  0
Handler_read_key    41
Handler_read_last   0
Handler_read_next   2561
Handler_read_prev   0
Handler_read_rnd    0
Handler_read_rnd_next   80
Handler_rollback    0
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  0
Handler_write   40
```

**Below it's Explain Data:**

```
1   PRIMARY mt      ref index5,messages_thread_creator_index,message_creator_other_index    message_creator_other_index 3   const   40  100.00  Using index; Rematerialize (<derived2>)
1   PRIMARY <derived2>      ALL                 2   100.00  
2   DEPENDENT DERIVED   m       ref messages_threadId_status_index,messages_threadId_index,messages_threadId_id_index   messages_threadId_status_index  258 tolet.mt.id 61  100.00  Using index
```

---

Comment: Test `ALTER TABLE messages_thread ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx1 (creator, id, other)`.

Comment: @Akina that not helping also. both results same.

Comment: Look EXPLAIN. What indexes are used? beautiful != visible and clear.

Comment: @Akina it using indexes but not optimized for max(id) values.

Comment: *not optimized for max(id) values* Grouping by one table, max by another... I cannot find the point fo optimize.

Comment: as a sub query is not it should use max()? in my second query i'm using sub-queries which created an materialization table but still not using optimize as normal. example if i run `select max(id) id from messages m where threadId='384423485251'` it optimize but when i run `SELECT m2.id, mt.other 
FROM messages_thread mt 
inner join ( select max(id) id, threadId 
           from messages m 
           group by threadId) as m2 on mt.id=m2.threadId
WHERE mt.creator=1` it's not optimizing, also not with `lateral`.

Comment: See the added tag.

Comment: I vote for the 2nd.  Note that, although it says "full table scan" is is referring to the _small_ intermediate table with only about 40 rows, not the original table with 2560 rows.

Comment: @RickJames me too using 2nd. also thanks for the updated tag, i'm studying on that tag to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8.0.14 has introduced [Lateral Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html). In your second query, you are computing `max()` value for all the `threadId`, whether you need it or not during the JOIN. You can avoid this materialization of `m2` (a costly process, which is basically temp table creation, either in-memory, or disk (if too big)), by using the following instead:

```sql
SELECT max(m2.id), mt.other 
FROM messages_thread mt 
join lateral ( select max(m.id) as id
               from messages m 
               where m.threadId = mt.id ) as m2
WHERE mt.creator=1 
group by other;
```

Also, try defining a new composite index on `messages_thread` table for [Group By Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html) in the main `SELECT` query: `(creator, other)`. You can benchmark this new query with and without new index suggestion, to decide whether to keep it or not.

Comment: `LATERAL()` not helping here with index or without index on (`creator, other`). it's processing same row what process my first query. Also it's still using materialization table.

Comment: yeah, i updated with it's performance data please see again

Comment: i also tried with lateral perviously but got same result,well i'm adding a db_fiddle, please wait some time.

Comment: previously i never used db-fiddle, i'm not fully known how to work with it. but i tried to make sql dump of my tables and the messages table is to big, its almost 701kb, that's large text file is possible to upload in db-fiddle? also there has no way to upload sql file only text input.

Comment: @Rhidoy just copy create table statement and some 200 insert statements (rows) from the SQL dump

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99402/discussion-between-rhidoy-and-madhur-bhaiya).

Comment: @Rhidoy check the first query in this fiddle utilizing a Correlated Subquery in the SELECT clause: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7HMfduM8rzkY6TPqWZcU6z/2 If this is also not efficient, then we probably are out of options

Comment: sorry i was little bit busy. after checking your first query its also showing that it access more rows than second one but it skips temp table creation. so i think number of rows it access is more important rather than temp table creation. maybe there some settings which can overcome temp creation by extend buffer size. again i'm not a guys from DBA, i'm just java programmer, so your advice will be more appreciate to choosing which query i need to use.

Comment: @Rhidoy you would need to increase `tmp_table_size` but do it only for this query and the session . Post query execution, reset it to original value. Worth a reading : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html

Comment: i read the link and thinking to keep it as how it is. maybe that's the highest optimization can be done for this query. thanks again for your value able times.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the plans 1-3 use Full Table Scan. It's probably not a problem with small tables (as far as I understand `messages_thread` has only 40 records). So if you expect the tables to grow and have variety of mt.creator values, then you would probably want to access `mt` by index and not scanning it.

I think the query optimizer would switch in this mode automatically once the tables grow. But if you want to see it with the current data, you may try to use hint:

```
SELECT max(m.id), mt.other 
FROM messages_thread mt USE INDEX(messages_thread_creator_index)
join messages m ON mt.id = m.threadId 
WHERE mt.creator=1 
group by mt.other;
```

Or create additional index:

```
create index mt_creator_thread_id_index on messages_thread(creator, id);
```

(But the latter is less likely to affect execution plan on small data.)

**Additional:**

Actually, on my system (5.7 with empty tables), Plan 2 doesn't use Full Table Scan either with or without `USE INDEX (message_threadId_id_index)`, it accesses `m2` by `<auto_key0>` index based on `mt.id` :

```
mysql> explain SELECT m2.id, mt.other  FROM messages_thread mt  inner join ( select max(id) id, threadId             from messages m             group by threadId) as m2 on mt.id=m2.threadId WHERE mt.creator=1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: mt
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,messages_thread_creator_index
          key: messages_thread_creator_index
      key_len: 3
          ref: const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived2>
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: <auto_key0>
          key: <auto_key0>
      key_len: 258
          ref: test.mt.id
         rows: 2
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: m
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: messages_threadId_status_index,message_threadId_id_index
          key: messages_threadId_status_index
      key_len: 260
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index


mysql> explain SELECT m2.id, mt.other  FROM messages_thread mt  inner join ( select max(id) id, threadId             from messages m USE INDEX (message_threadId_id_index)            group by threadId) as m2 on mt.id=m2.threadId WHERE mt.creator=1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: mt
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,messages_thread_creator_index
          key: messages_thread_creator_index
      key_len: 3
          ref: const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived2>
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: <auto_key0>
          key: <auto_key0>
      key_len: 258
          ref: test.mt.id
         rows: 2
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: m
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: messages_threadId_status_index,message_threadId_id_index
          key: message_threadId_id_index
      key_len: 266
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
```

It still shows `Rows: 2` for the derived table, but that's probably an estimate made by query optimizer and not that it actually reads two records for every id value.

Comment: actually the main problem is with messages table max(m.id) it's not optimizing, nor with `sub-queries` or nor with `lateral`. messages_thread table is ok here.

Comment: You mean you want max() to be received from index and not a calculated group? Like having (mt.other, m.id) index? I don’t see how it could be done in MySQL. Maybe materialized view feature of other database engines could help here.

Comment: On the other hand, plan 3 doesn’t have GROUP step, it really gets max() from index in some sense. Another thought is that you could move or duplicate creator and other fields from mt to m. Then JOIN wouldn’t be needed at all.

Comment: yeah, plan 2 or plan 3 is the discussion material, in plan 3 with materialized table it should use index and optimize max(), the problem is it using index but not optimizing it. that the problem why it do not optimizing max? what you think? and move field from mt to m is just waste of space because those filed related only with mt.

Comment: Ah, you probably mean plan 3 should use `message_threadId_id_index` and not `messages_threadId_status_index`. Can you try to just hint it to the sub-query? But I don't understand why it wasn't chosen in the first place.

Comment: yeah i tryed but result is same as plan 2.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without being able to test on the same data. Can you also try to hint m2 as leading table in Plan 2?

Comment: i checked your updated answer. you also mention that it still use `2 rows`, I don't think that actually estimate value because the Query Statistic give same result as it's scanning two rows. also here is an issues with materialize table. I did lot of test on this query and find out that plan two is much optimized than any others quires i tried. so maybe if no better solution find out i have to stick on plan 2.

Comment: And what do you get for the SESSION values?